# JavaScript/Forge: Aes cipher where input length equals output length

Tags: javascript, encryption, aes

I am using [Forge](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge#cipher) as Crypto-library for JavaScript and I try to encrypt an 20-bit message, where the encrypted message **must** be 20 bits again.

When I try AES-CBC for example, and try to encrypt "01101011100100101100" for example, I get "ac2b0ba323315116274aca604730972d" as result, which does not help me at all (since I am looking to get same length back).

Is there any way to solve this problem? If not with Forge, or with AES, what else could I use?

Comment: The short answer is format preserving encryption (FPE). The long answer, unfortunately, is also format preserving encryption as this is not something that usually comes with generic crypto libraries.